# Is it possible to show border on preview, but not when printing

Tags: reporting-services, printing, rdlc, rdl

I created an rdlc report by visual studio 2013.

The report has a table with a border but it will print on paper which a paper has a template.

Printing will fill only the detail without border.

Below figure is an example of the template paper.

[image]

So I need to preview with table border when printed not show the border.

[image]

I know I can make two reports for preview and print out, but it 's out of my scope of work.

The printing function used by the reportViewer is a VB coding.

So I need to know is it possible to do something in rdlc report (reporting service)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google of the question led me to [here](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/)

Using the Built in Field called `Render Format Name` you can perform an equation on the Border style so that different formats render the border differently.  For example if you wanted to print the report without the border, but with otherwise you would set the Border to

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name <> "IMAGE", "Solid", "None")
```

And taken from that link above, here is a table of export types and how these should be included in the expression

```
Renderer                  |  RenderFormat.Name | RenderFormat.IsInteractive
--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------
Preview in BIDS           | RPL                | True
XML file with report data | XML                | False
CSV (comma delimited)     | CSV                | False
TIFF file or Print button | IMAGE              | False
PDF                       | PDF                | False
MHTML (web archive)       | MHTML              | True
Excel                     | EXCEL              | False
Word                      | WORD               | False
```

Comment: I don't know what render format  if I click print button on toolbar of ReportViewer for print direct to printer.

Comment: If i use reportViewer so Renderformat.Name = "RPL". But I think if I preview or print to printer. A Renderformat is not different.